# Too many connections for redis with last cmd as "unsubscribe"

Tags: azure-redis-cache

I am using the StackExchange.Redis nuget for Azure Redis, however, lately, I notice too many connections and almost all of them showing the last command executed at either "info" or 
"unsubscribe". See the extract from "Client List" here:

id=698869 addr=<> fd=5291 name=<> age=1037 idle=5 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 ow=0 owmem=0 events=r **cmd=info** numops=30
id=698871 addr=<> fd=20761 name=<>age=1037 idle=5 flags=N db=0 sub=1 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 ow=0 owmem=0 events=r **cmd=unsubscribe** numops=23
id=698879 addr=<> fd=19839 name=<> age=1037 idle=5 flags=N db=0 sub=1 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 ow=0 owmem=0 events=r **cmd=unsubscribe** numops=24

I need help in understanding why these "info" and "unsubscribe" commands are getting triggered from the nuget? I am sure that I myself am not sending these commands from the code that uses the nuget.
My code only does "GET" and "SET" via the nuget.

Answer (score -1):

StackExchange.Redis periodically sends the "info replication" command to redis to get details about the server. Also, by default the StackExchange.Redis client opens two connections to Redis on each ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect() call, one call is for interactive commands from the client, the other connection is for pub/sub. If you are not using pub/sub, you can disable the second connection by disabling the subscribe command via the ConfigurationOptions().